# MediaWiki HTML and CSS formatting problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, mediawiki

So I've been working on a wiki which uses MediaWiki (I've had to change my whole code to deal with the engine as I can't use normal HTML in this case).

The wiki is linked [here](http://2013hs.igem.org/Team%3aSt_Pauls_London).

The problem I have is that the content of the wiki isn't pushing the main page content down (as you can see by visiting the wiki).

All resources are found within the wiki (no external referencing). I do have some jquery down but I've added that as a later test, the formatting didn't work before I added that.

I feel the problem is something to do with my css and positioning values but I can't figure it out.

You can view the source code that I've put into the engine [here](http://pastebin.com/DjQiJd8H).

Any help if very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't close your header  on line 332

```
  <html>
 <a class="nav_buttonLink" id="nav-button-link-fourth" href="#fourth"><div 
class="nav_button" id="fourth"><p class="nav_buttonText">
</html>
NOTEBOOK
<html>
 </p></div></a>
</html>
 |-
 |}
</center>*</div>*
```

Comment: Exactly it! Thank you very much.